# Getting first occurrence in last sequence with data

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I need to to get the first occurrence in the last sequence of data inserted to database. It would be great if it could be done in one query.

Let's say I have data like this:

```
{_id:......,ts:Date("2017-10-24T00:00:00.000Z"), id: 1, ok: false}
{_id:......,ts:Date("2017-10-23T00:00:00.000Z"), id: 1, ok: false}
{_id:......,ts:Date("2017-10-22T00:00:00.000Z"), id: 1, ok: true}
{_id:......,ts:Date("2017-10-21T00:00:00.000Z"), id: 1, ok: true}
{_id:......,ts:Date("2017-10-20T00:00:00.000Z"), id: 1, ok: false}
{_id:......,ts:Date("2017-10-21T00:00:00.000Z"), id: 2, ok: false}
{_id:......,ts:Date("2017-10-20T00:00:00.000Z"), id: 2, ok: true}
```

and I need to get for every ID the first occurrence when the field ok was false in the last sequence when the ok is false.

```
{_id:......,ts:Date("2017-10-23T00:00:00.000Z"), id: 1, ok: false}
```

but I need it for every id. It seems impossible for me to do it scalable so I won't need x thousand of queries to the database. I know how to make it for one ID but if I would need to send query for every ID the database would be overwhelmed.

This is my current query:

```
{
    $sort : {ts : -1}
},
{
    $match : {"ok" : true }
},
{
    $group : {
        _id : {id : "$id"},
        last : {$last : "$$CURRENT"}
    }
}
```

This gives me for every id the last data with ok true.

But I need the data after it. Is there any simple scalable way how to do it for the ok false ??

I tried to use foreach function on aggregate but if I do that I get error

> TypeError: db.getCollection(...).aggregate(...).foreach is not a function

So I don't know then ... is it even possible to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I think you did not pass a function as a parameter of ForEach:

```
db.getCollection(...).aggregate(...).ForEach(function(myDoc) { 
                        print( myDoc.ts ); 
                        });
```

Then regarding the aggregation, I am not sure this is possible. As the document are somewhat linked by a virtual sequence. I would do it as follow:

- create a cursor with a query sorted by date and id.
- iterate it with ForEach  (this will pull the data by sequences of 20
  docs , you won't end up with the whole collection in memory (either on client or DB))
- have a few if statements that checks if the sequence is true/false and print the first occurrence of the last false sequence.